# ordenamiento de una tabla en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ordenamiento, orderby

tengo el siguiente problema al tratar de ordenar mis datos que me devuelve un query
tengo los siguientes datos en una tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eso me devuelve al hacer "SELEC * FROM tabla"

Pero quisiera que al hacer la consulta se me ordenara conforme al "id_desc", pero con los que tiene conexión este id que son los de "catalogo_dependiente_padre"
ya intente varias formas pero no se como hacer este ordenamiento ya que "id_desc" y "catalogo_dependiente_padre" es el mismo id y tendría que quedar así el ordenamiento

-La idea es que , al llegar a un id de la columna "id_desc" y esta exista dentro de la columna "catalogo_dependiente_padre" se listen los datos que tienen ese mismo id, lo coloco en color verde espero sea mas entendible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien me pueda orientar , De antemano Gracias

Comment: pues la verdad no entiendo la lógica de orden que quieres...

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer es algo como un árbol de N niveles? Vas recorriendo la rama 1,2,7-8-9, luego 1,3,10,11, luego 1,4, luego 1,5m luego 1,6?

Comment: ya edite mi post, por si no se entendía , si es algo asi como un arbol , que en cuanto el id de la columna id_desc , exista dentro de la otra columna "catalogo_dependiente_padre" se listen los de ese mismo id

Comment: no entiendo por qué por ejemplo el id_desc 3 no va antes, si su catalogo_dependiente_padre es 1 y ya existe antes....es muy confuso el criterio

Answer (score 0):

Según tu pregunta creo que lo que puedes necesitar se aproxima al hecho de usar condicionales en la cláusula en `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY ORDER BY IF(id_desc>catalogo_dependiente_padre, catalogo_dependiente_padre, id_desc);
```

Por si te ayuda puedes ampliar información en [DataBase Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229741/is-possible-to-use-order-by-with-if-else-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución mucho mas simple para MySql 8.0 ó superior, que la que propuse originalmente, en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507624/15424227). Utilizando una query `recursiva CTE` y generando el path (utiliznado la columna `id_desc` para ello) hacía cada nodo (partiendo del nodo raiz).

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT *, CONCAT('/', id_desc) AS path, 1 AS nivel
                       FROM t
                       WHERE catalogo_dependiente_padre = 0
                       
                       UNION ALL
                       
                       SELECT t.id_desc, t.catalogo_dependiente_padre, CONCAT(path, '/', t.id_desc) AS path, nivel + 1 AS nivel
                       FROM cte
                       INNER JOIN t ON cte.id_desc = t.catalogo_dependiente_padre)
                       
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY path;
```

**Esta fue mi primera respuesta:**

Según entiendo lo que tu buscas es ordenar la tabla recursivamente. Quizas lo mas simple es utilizar algún lenguaje de programación para hacerlo. Yo implementé una solución para `MySql` con un procedimiento almacenado recursivo.

Para ello creo una tabla auxiliar donde voy a ir guardando los registros en el orden deseado, en cada fila agrego una cadena con el momento en el que inserté dicha fila, la cual permitirá listar los registros en el orden deseado. En lugar de la fecha y hora, quizas lo mas adecuado hubiera sido utilizar un contador (el cual debería ser pasado como parámetro al procedimiento).

```
-- Creo la tabla auxiliar donde voy a ir guardando los registros en el orden deseado:
  
CREATE TABLE t_aux (
   id_desc int, 
   catalogo_dependiente_padre int, 
   tiempo varchar(100)
);


--Procedimiento almacenado recursivo:

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ordenrecursivo;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ordenrecursivo(IN padre INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a, b INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id_desc, catalogo_dependiente_padre FROM t WHERE catalogo_dependiente_padre = padre ORDER BY id_desc ASC;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  
  SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 50;
  
  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO t_aux (id_desc, catalogo_dependiente_padre, tiempo) VALUES (a, b, current_timestamp(6));
    
    CALL ordenrecursivo(a);
    
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
   
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Ejecuto el procedimiento (le paso como parámetro el catalogo_dependiente_padre del primer registro, que sería la raiz del arbol):

```
--Antes de ejecutar el procedimiento hay que limpiar la tabla auxiliar:
TRUNCATE t_aux;

CALL ordenrecursivo(0);
```

Luego para listar las filas ordenas según el orden deseado (consultando la tabla auxiliar):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_aux 
ORDER BY tiempo ASC;
```